# multiple external urls in wordpress website

Tags: plugins

I am working over a wordpress website which is basically a union of wordpress + their official website which is in php.

In wordpress I am simply showing wordpress data. but when user need to create something , then user is directed to that official website.

Example 1. Create new flower from the flower page (I have content page for flower) 2. Create new fruit from Fruit page

I just want to know the standard way to manage all these number of external urls rather than giving a static links for all of them.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not completely sure what you mean but if you're wanting to keep all the links represented in the Wordpress system you could use the 'page links to' plugin and create a Wordpress page for each of the external links - http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/page-links-to/

Then link to the Wordpress page version from within your Wordpress pages.